# css "resize:horizontal" doesn't work if the child has "flex:1"

Tags: css

**css**

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.child {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: horizontal;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: There can be many children. I don't know the width of them.

Comment: Example: I want to shrink the left element. I expect the right element to grow.

Comment: Change `flex:1` to `flex: 1 1 auto;`

Comment: I've tried that but there is a "jump" on the left element.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JjRaKpJ

Comment: The "resize" icon jumps to the right. Is there a way to fix that?